# npm package.json - remove directory if it exists

Tags: bash, npm, webpack

I am using the following logic within my package.json file for a webpack project:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ",
    "clean": "rm -r deploy",
    "start": "npm run clean && npm run dev && webpack-dev-server --mode development"
  },
```

If my `deploy` directory does not exist, and I run `npm start`, I get the following message in my terminal:

```
rm: cannot remove 'deploy': No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to check if the directory exist first? And if does, then just skip the clean process?

Comment: Can you just add the -f option to rm to force it to ignore the error (e.g. rm -rf deploy), or do you actually need to check for existence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its better to use [`clean-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin)

but here you can also use `rm -rf deploy`.